# Scenarios definition for JWT/API Process with Cucumber/Behat

Tags: cucumber, behat

I have a scenario where basically:
- Authorized (JWT) user access my API
- If user exists, info get synched with DB, if not, gets created
- ETC ETC

My question is, how would I proceed creating this scenario? There's a lot (ok, 4) parameters that should be in the request, but I don't want to polute the scenario with information that can confuse a normal user reading the scenario.

This is what I have:

```
  Scenario: Non Existent user access the API
    Given an authorized user access the API
    And user does not exist on API database
    When user access the API
    Then user details are added to API database
    And user does exist on API database
```

A user accessing the api will have: email, auth0_id, nickname and name. Just not sure if I should code those info on the Scenario or somehow do it on the Context file.

Edit:
Can I have some "parameters" to be set IN the Context file, instead of in the .feature file? i.e. On the feature file I say "Non existent user access the application" and inside the Context file, in the function associated with this step, I make sure I create a user that does not exist on the database and so on? Would this be a good way of keeping thinks separated from  the .feature scenarios?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
Scenario: API - new user access the API
   Given I have a new user
   When I access the API with the new user
   Then the user is added to the API database
```

First step would generate the user details and save them in a variable, second would make the call to the api (using the saved variable and generate the JWT) and the last one will check the details in the api.

You can declare `new` as parameter like:

`@Then /^I access the API with the (new|other_user) user$/`

Anyway, you should declare it as simple as possible in a manner that has sense to you can that you can easily reuse.

Comment: That's nice - So every "step" can wither prepare the scenario and/or assert something. Thanks, was really helpful

Comment: You define the actions that you need in the steps and check for example the call to the api is successful and in the final step you can do the detailed validation.